# How I can sort whole data in different pages of my kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a kendo gird. When I sort my grid, It doesn't sort next page data. It is only sorted on first page. I want to sort whole data in the grid. How can I do it??

```
$("#ProductGrid").kendoGrid({
          columns: [
 { field: "ProductID", title: 'Product Id' ,width:50},
 { field: "ProductName", title:  'Product Name' },
 { field: "Price", title: 'Price' },            
 ],
  groupable: true,
  sortable: true,
  pageable: true,
  dataBound: function () {
                this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            },

  scrollable: true,
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
       read: "../api/Product/FindByPartyIDForGrid?partyID=" + PartyID

             },
  serverPaging: true,
  serverSorting: true,
  pageSize: 50,
  schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Count"
          }
       })
});
```

My server side method

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[ActionName("FindByPartyIDForGrid")]
public Responce FindByPartyIDForGrid(string partyID)
{
    int take = httpRequest["take"] == null ? 10 : int.Parse(httpRequest["take"]);
    int skip = httpRequest["skip"] == null ? 0 : int.Parse(httpRequest["skip"]);
       var content = new ProductBS().FindByPartyID(Convert.ToInt32(partyID));
      if (content != null)
      {
       return new Models.Responce(content.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray(), content.Count());
      }
      else
      {
       return new Responce(new Array[0], 0);
      }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is not a client side (kendo) issue. Kendo grid is configured correct as I can see. In your `FindByPartyIDForGrid` method you need to do the sorting and return relevant page correctly.

Check your server logic, If you can post it here we can have a look in to it.

**EDIT**
Seems like you haven't handle the sorting in the server,you have two options,

1.You can do it using [Odata protpcol](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx)
 2.  You can do it by handling [sorting yourself](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-08-09/ask_kendo_ui_ndash_server_side_sorting_with_webapi.aspx),

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you have enabled serverSorting. Then you should perform the sorting yourself.

If you don't bind the grid to lots items you can use client-side sorting. Simply remove the `serverSorting: true` option of the data source.